# Kotlin : Inheritance and issue with parcelable data

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, parcelable

I am trying to get my head around an issue and i couldn't find any particular solution.

Base Class

```
open class FeedBase() : Parcelable{

var type : String =""

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
    type=parcel.readString()
}

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(type)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<FeedBase> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): FeedBase {
        return FeedBase(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<FeedBase?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}}
```

Item Class holding data class & extending Base class

```
@Parcelize
data class FeedItem(var feed:Feed) : FeedBase()
```

& Data class

```
@Parcelize
data class Feed(var test:String,var score:Int) : Parcelable
```

Now I am trying to send my data across activities and I am creating my object like below

```
val feedItem = FeedItem(Feed("yolo", 1000))
feedItem.type="test"
```

but I am not able to get the correct **type**(var in Base class). It gets empty whenever I receive the object from parcelable intent in another activity but Item data is preserved. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

> [`@Parcelize` requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#how-to-use)

So it has no idea about `type`. In the code generated by `@Parcelize`, you basically have

```
companion object CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<FeedItem> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): FeedItem{
        val feed = Feed.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)
        return FeedItem(feed)
    }
}
```

Note that the `FeedBase`'s implementation of `Parcelable` doesn't matter. If you think about it, it *couldn't* be used: if you had

```
val feedBase = FeedBase.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)
```

there's no way to turn this `FeedBase` instance into a `FeedItem` instance.

You'll need to write custom logic for this case by implementing `Parceler` in the companion object.

Comment: Yes, I have read that but my base class is not using @Parcelize annotation. For that, I wrote Parcelable creator. Is this the wrong approach ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what your base class uses, what matters is that `type` isn't a constructor parameter for the subclass.

Comment: I've added something to explain _why_ `FeedBase` implementation isn't used by `@Parcelize`, maybe it'll help.